# How to create a PHP project with IntelliJ Idea 9?

Tags: php, intellij-idea

I can't find how to create PHP project with IntelliJ Idea 9. It only offers "Java module" and "Maven module" to choose when creating a project. PHP plugin is installed, but how to employ it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Web module type is available since IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 11. Use Web module type to create PHP projects in IDEA.

---

**Old answer prior to IDEA 11:**

It's a known limitation, IDEA doesn't support creating project without any module type like PhpStorm/WebStorm products since it supports many languages and technologies. But it also doesn't have a special module type for PHP or web projects yet.

At the moment you should use dummy Java module, you can omit creation of the src directory and all the other Java specific stuff, but you have to choose Java module type for your PHP/web projects.

This may change in the future IDEA versions as we plan to [support opening PhpStorm/WebStorm projects in IDEA and vice versa](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-1624).

There is also a [request to support web modules in IntelliJ IDEA](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-63305) that you can watch for progress.

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward, it'd be very good to have "one IDE to rule them all" instead of many IDEs based on same engine.

Comment: This does not answer the question IMHO - we need a way to create, not only open php projects from IDEA.

Comment: @RonaldoSantana, it's answered in the update, use Web module type to create PHP projects in IDEA.

Answer (score 3):

I'm on IDEA 11.0.2 and I still have to create a barebones Foo.java file in the non-Java module I want to create. So frustrating. Meaning that if I want to create a module for my JavaScript project or for my PHP project I need to put that file in there and do New module...from existing sources, then delete the Foo.java.

There's got to be a better way!

Comment: Know it is a old stuff - but just bought IDEA and this really is a big down side to me - I go down the same path as you